# Display woocommerce 'payment method' in Order Notes section in the Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to pass the payment method to the order notes section of a Woocommerce Order (when viewing the order in the backend)

This field gets imported into our ShipStation software. Right now, I have no way of knowing what payment method a customer used when viewing an order from ShipStation. (we give a free gift when a certain payment method is used.)

Answer (score 0):

At first, viewing the payment method in Wordpress Admin is available. You just have to enable it in Screen Options.
If you want to add the Shipment method into the order note, you need to just add this to your functions.php:

```
add_action( ‘woocommerce_new_order’, ‘add_engraving_notes’, 1, 1 );
function add_engraving_notes( $order_id ) {
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$note = $order->getShippingMethod();;
$order->add_order_note( $note );
$order->save();
}
```